# Aggregate documents after limiting them by a certain amount for a specific property

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, lodash

I need to find all the scores of users, pick only the two best scores for each user and finally sum those scores to create a leaderboard.

Let me give an example of what I'm looking for and what I've tried already but with no success.

```
Users Collection:
[
  {user: "userA", score:10, game: 12},
  {user: "userA", score:20, game: 12},
  {user: "userA", score:7, game: 12},
  {user: "userB", score:10, game: 12},
  {user: "userB", score:3, game: 12},
  {user: "userB", score:7, game: 12}
]
```

What I would like to end up with is this:

```
[
  {user:"userA", score:30, game:12},
  {user:"userB", score:17, game:12}
]
```

I've tried going the mongo way with aggregation but unfortunately you cannot $sort, $limit on the $group stage of the aggregation meaning you cannot pick the two best scores only.

Is there a way to do this maybe with mapReduce or even with Lodash by manipulating the returned documents of a simple find() query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use lodash's [`_.sortBy()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.15.0#sortBy), [`_.groupBy()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.15.0#groupBy), and [`_.map()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.15.0#map) to get the 2 highest scores of each user and sum them:

```js
var arr = [
  {user: "userA", score:10, game: 12},
  {user: "userA", score:20, game: 12},
  {user: "userA", score:7, game: 12},
  {user: "userB", score:10, game: 12},
  {user: "userB", score:3, game: 12},
  {user: "userB", score:7, game: 12}
];

var result = _(arr) // start a lodash's chain
  .sortBy(function(value) { // sort the array descending
    return -value.score;
  })
  .groupBy('user') // group by the user
  .map(function(arr) { // map each user
    var score = arr[0].score + (arr[1] ? arr[1].score : 0); // the score should be a combination of the 1st two items (if there are two)
    return Object.assign({}, arr[0], { score, score }); // assign to new object, with the calculated score
  })
  .value(); // extract the result from the chain

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.15.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Also, for the sake of completion I think that there should be a final sortBy in the end of the chain in order to have a sorted leaderboard.